# Cambiar el valor de un input creado en un Componente React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, botón, input

Estoy realizando el juego del tic-tac-toe (tateti) y he realizado el componente 'MyButtons', donde yo devuelvo un input y ahi realizo la logica para que se pueda mostrar la 'X' o la 'O'. El problema es que cuando quiero darle click a otro input me devuelve el mismo simbolo, en este caso la 'O' pero si le vuelvo a dar click me devuelve la 'X' y así con los demas inputs.
Quiero saber como poder darle click a cada uno de los inputs sin que se repita el simbolo anterior, es decir si clickeamos y nos devuelve el simbolo X, el proximo input tendra que devolver el simbolo O y asi hasta completar todos los inputs.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js">


function App() {
  return (
   
    <div>
      <Table></Table>
    </div>

  );
}

class Table extends React.Component {

    render (){

        return (

            <table border="2">
            <tr><td><MyButtons></MyButtons></td><td><MyButtons></MyButtons></td><td><MyButtons></MyButtons></td></tr>
            <tr><td><MyButtons></MyButtons></td><td><MyButtons></MyButtons></td><td><MyButtons></MyButtons></td></tr>
            <tr><td><MyButtons></MyButtons></td><td><MyButtons></MyButtons></td><td><MyButtons></MyButtons></td></tr>
        </table>

        )
       
    }
}

export default Table;

class MyButtons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value:null,
            nextPlay: true,
        };
    }

    turns(value){

       value = this.state.nextPlay ? 'X':'O'
            this.setState({
                value: value,
               nextPlay: !this.state.nextPlay
            })
            this.setState({
                value: value,
               nextPlay: !this.state.nextPlay
            })
           
        }
    
    render () {
        return (
            <input type="button" value= {this.state.value} onClick={()=>this.turns(this)}></input>
        )
    }
}

export default MyButtons;



export default App;


</script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Porque estás actualizando dos veces el estado? Tienes dos veces seguidas la instrucción de setState, ¿por qué?

Comment: Por que pensaba que cuando una vez que le doy click en el primer input me va a devolver el simbolo : 'X', y despues cuando haga click en el proximo input me devolveria el simbolo 'O' y asi alternandose pero no esta funcionando de esa forma

Comment: No, y creo que el problema es realmente dónde está tu estado. El estado va a aplicarse solamente en el botón y no en la tabla. Es decir, cada botón tiene un estado independiente. Dicho estado no es global. Por lo que la lógica de los clicks debería estar en la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que se encarga de llevar el control de qué jugada se realizará y de llevar control de los clicks y los botones debe ser la tabla. Si lo haces en el botón, el estado del botón será independiente al de la tabla. Es decir, el estado de react es por clase y no es global por cada aplicación.

Modifiqué tu código para que la tabla lleve el estado de todo el juego.
Puedes probar la aplicación entrando en el siguiente link:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/determined-river-z18fp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Básicamente el código modificado es el siguiente:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table />
    </div>
  );
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentMove: true,
      clickedButtons: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    };

    this.clickButton = this.clickButton.bind(this);
  }

  clickButton(idx) {
    console.log(this.state);
    let index = parseInt(idx);
    if (index === -1) {
      return;
    }

    let storedValue = this.state.clickedButtons[index];
    if (storedValue.length !== 0) {
      return;
    }

    let value = this.state.currentMove ? "x" : "o";
    let clickedButtons = this.state.clickedButtons;
    clickedButtons[index] = value;
    this.setState({
      currentMove: !this.state.currentMove,
      clickedButtons: clickedButtons
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table border="2">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <MyButton
              index={0}
              value={this.state.clickedButtons[0]}
              clickAction={this.clickButton}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <MyButton
              index={1}
              value={this.state.clickedButtons[1]}
              clickAction={this.clickButton}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <MyButton
              index={2}
              value={this.state.clickedButtons[2]}
              clickAction={this.clickButton}
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <MyButton
              index={3}
              value={this.state.clickedButtons[3]}
              clickAction={this.clickButton}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <MyButton
              index={4}
              value={this.state.clickedButtons[4]}
              clickAction={this.clickButton}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <MyButton
              index={5}
              value={this.state.clickedButtons[5]}
              clickAction={this.clickButton}
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <MyButton
              index={6}
              value={this.state.clickedButtons[6]}
              clickAction={this.clickButton}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <MyButton
              index={7}
              value={this.state.clickedButtons[7]}
              clickAction={this.clickButton}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <MyButton
              index={8}
              value={this.state.clickedButtons[8]}
              clickAction={this.clickButton}
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="button"
        value={this.props.value}
        onClick={() => this.props.clickAction(this.props.index)}
      ></input>
    );
  }
}

MyButton.defaultProps = {
  value: "",
  index: -1
};
```

Al mismo tiempo, llevo un arreglo para tener control de que casillas ya hice click para no volver a modificarlas una vez que tienen un `x` o un `o`.